Неполное двусоставное или или просто двусоставное?

Вот предложение: "Экзамены близко!"

Предположим, что пропущен полноценный глагол "подступили", то тогда "близко" нужно считать обстоятельством?
Может ли "наречие" в данном случае взять на себя функцию полноценного сказуемого? Дело тогда, получается,в подходках к выделению основы?

Экзамены близко!
Это двусоставное предложение, составное именное сказуемое, связка в настоящем времени нулевая, именная часть выражена наречием близко.
ТЕОРИЯ
Кустова Г.И. Синтаксис современного русского языка
Составное именное сказуемое, стр.72
Типы связок:

незнаменательная: глагол быть (в наст, времени имеет нулевую форму);

Именная часть:

наречие: Сосед навеселе; Он с ними заодно; Друзья
рядом;


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

@sharon Скажите,пожалуйста, еще. Во фразе "Я был в отпуске!" надо ли включать " в отпуске" в состав сказуемого? Вроде бы я был = я присутствовал, находился. Я еще сравнила с данной фразой: я был в отпуске 2 раза за этот год = я брал отпуск 2 раза за этот год.

Я думаю, что надо включить. Смотрю словарь:  БЫТЬ. 8. (в наст. вр. с опущением; обычно с сущ. с предлогом). Находиться, пребывать в каком-л. состоянии, положении и т.п. Б. на излечении. Б. в переделке, в разъездах. Б. в добром расположении духа, в отчаянии. Б. в переписке с кем-л. Я (был) в восторге!  Это СОСТОЯНИЕ, поэтому признаковое значение. У Кустовой стр 72, 7) предложно-падежный оборот: Все были в восторге / в страхе/в отчаянии; Все небо 0 в тучах; Вся одежда 0 в грязи; Деревня под обстрелом',  Сравнить: Я был отпускником, то есть отдыхал от работы.
